# CSS calc() not working correctly with em in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a simple scenario where I would like two boxes to display next to each other and to take the full width of the page, with 0.75em margin between them. Here is my markup:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 0.375em); /* 0.375 * (2 boxes) = 0.75 */
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

.box:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This works correctly on Chrome, but when I try to load it in IE11, the second box wraps to the next line. I have set the font-size on the html element to 16px. Interestingly, if I replace 0.375em with 6px (16px * 0.375 = 6px), the boxes show up correctly on one line in IE11. Any thoughts anyone?

Here is a JSFiddle where you can see this not working in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcuu8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE miscalculates `0.375em` when `em` equals `16px`. Instead of the mathematically correct result 6px, it gets `5.92px`. This can be seen by setting the width of an element to `0.375em` and inspecting the element in developer tools. There you can see that IE also shows the declared with as `0.37em`, so it seems to drop any digits after `0.37`! This happens also when using simply `width: 0.375em`, without using `calc()` at all.

In this case, the bug makes the width of each box a fraction of a pixel larger than it should be, and thus the second box does not fit on the right of the first a box.

A simple solution is to use integers. Mathematically, 0.375 equals 3/8, so you would replace

```
width: calc(50% - 0.375em)
```

by

```
width: calc(50% - 3em/8)
```

Comment: Thanks for you knowledgable answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the way IE is handling the percentage. My suggestion would be to simplify and allow IE to handle the percentage differently.
I've created an alternative method in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcuu8/7/)

Where I've created wrappers

```
<div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box"></div></div>
<div class="boxWrapper"><div class="box"></div></div>
```

And then set your CSS  to handle the margin inside the wrappers

```
html, body { font-size: 16px; }
.boxWrapper {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}
.box {
    height : 5em;
    background: slategray;
    margin-right: 0.375em;
    display:block;
}
.boxWrapper:last-child .box {
    margin-left: 0.375em;
    margin-right:0;
    background: silver;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `calc` function is working correctly. But the problem comes from the decimal number you have used for calculation.

In Chrome the values are truncated. For ex, `50, 50.5` and `50.6` all show the same width in chrome which IE does not.

Use rounded values in the calculation part, you will get the desired result in IE and Chrome.

```
 .box {
 float: left;
 width: calc(50% - 0.4em); /* 0.375 * (2 boxes) = 0.75 */
 margin-right: 0.8em;
 }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcuu8/9/)

Comment: If you look at the computed value for the width in Chrome, you will see that Chrome is not truncating the ems. Your suggested solution works in that the boxes stay on the same line, but the boxes no longer take up full width.